# Multiselect dropdown in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropdownbox

I have a requirement to design the dropdown with multiselect option with checkbox using ASP.NET controls and also i need to select checkboxes while binding the values on the dropdown. Please help

Comment: please try this url http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Comment: Hi Sanjay, Thanks for your quick response. The Url provided by you is releated to query dropdown but i need typical ASP.NET dropdown with mutiselect

Comment: above link is provide you to create multi select checkbox list using jquery .here you can add drop down list,script provide in above link is convert into multiple checkbox and store selected item value in hiddenfields.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use following open source library to get your goal its simple and really amazing**

```
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay..i am looking ASP.NET dropdown control with multi select option.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, I developed this similar dropdown for my project.

```js
//Multiple Dropdown Select
    $('.multiDrop').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', function (){
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.wrapMulDrop').length) {
            $('.wrapMulDrop ul').slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('.wrapMulDrop ul li input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
       
        var x = $('.wrapMulDrop ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        if (x != "") {
            $('.multiDrop').html(x + " " + "selected");
        } else if (x < 1) {
            $('.multiDrop').html('Select Templates<i style="float:right;" class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i>');
        }
    });
```

```css
.wrapMulDrop {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.multiDrop {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #999;
    text-align: left;
}
.multiDrop:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.wrapMulDrop ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}
.wrapMulDrop ul li {
  
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #e5801d;
    padding: 1% 6%;
}
.wrapMulDrop ul li:hover {
    background-color: #33414e;
}
.wrapMulDrop ul li label {
    width: 100% !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 !important;
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapMulDrop">
  <button type="button" class="multiDrop">Select Templates<i style="float:right;" class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown"></i>
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="list1">
      <label for="list1">Template 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="list2">
      <label for="list2">Template 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="list3">
      <label for="list3">Template 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="list4">
      <label for="list4">Template 4</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have created the multiselect dropdown control with while scrolling the page the list is in fixed position

Comment: here is the code
<td><div align="left"><asp:TextBox ID="ddCoveragesSelect1" Text="<Select>" Width="78%" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox someinput" OnClick="return showPnl();"></asp:TextBox><asp:Panel ID="PnlCust" runat="server" CssClass="PnlDesign" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:99;width:270px"><asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="getUniqueValues(this);">

Comment: <asp:ListItem>Select All</asp:ListItem></asp:CheckBoxList><asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server"onclick="getUniqueValues(this);"></asp:CheckBoxList> </asp:Panel></div></td>